# mono dependencies on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dependencies, glibc, mono

I am trying to install mono as described [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-centos). In the root shell...

```
su root
```

I tried following command

```
yum install mono-devel
```

as mentioned on the web-page, but got stuck at installation of dependencies with following error message.

> Error: Package: mono-devel-6.4.0.198-0.xamarin.3.epel8.x86_64
>   (mono-centos8-stable)
>              Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit) Error: Package: libmono-llvm0-6.4.0.198-0.xamarin.3.epel8.x86_64 (mono-centos8-stable)
>              Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) Error: Package: libgdiplus0-6.0.2-0.xamarin.1.epel8.x86_64
>   (mono-centos8-stable)
>              Requires: libpng16.so.16()(64bit)

I tried installing glibc for CentOS7 as described [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) like this

```
yum install glibc
```

But the output says

> Package glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

Need guidance.

Comment: Apparently your EPEL.repo is for CentOS **8**, not CentOS 7 ! .... Sorry. Not usable. The packages are for CentOS **8** only.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I plan to compile mono as described [here](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/linux/). Will that be any better?

Comment: Compiling mono as described in the link above solved the problem. Thanks!